# ListIterators .next() will advance to next even inside the if condition?

Tags: java, iterator

In Java List Iterators, using iterator.next() take it to next value even it is used inside an if statement?

```
if (iterator.next() == "A") {...}
```

Comment: yes,  read about iterators more. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-iterator-in-java/

Comment: What the method do does not depend on the context of use ;)

Comment: Are you asking if `iterator.next()` always advances the pointer? If so, "yes" is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, next() method always advances to the next value even when used inside the if condition. Below is the method description,

```
 /**
 * Returns the next element in the iteration.
 *
 * @return the next element in the iteration
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iteration has no more elements
 */
 E next();
```